# What regexp to look for "5 digits or more" EXCEPT if starting with a chain of character

Tags: regex

My application is reading subject of emails and try to find file reference of user account into it.

The pb is that it is sent by users and can arrive in many different orders of course, with dates and also wrong reference to skip.

We are using a basic regexp that usually works pretty well for :

```
DOSSIER 4491128 - PPI Claim Benefit Calculation
4471631
Leistungsnr. 4445929
```

=> we catch respectively

```
4491128
4471631
4445929
```

And we can make use of these references to call our systems to retrieve information about users.

But we have a few cases like this where it's totally not working,

```
WG: SCM1177278 9910808067RSV Meldung
WG: SCM1161874 9909827071
WG: SCM1165728 9910855395 RSV
```

=> Here i want to skip `SCM1177278` or `SCM1161874` or `SCM1165728` and catch only the 2nd number `9910808067` or `9909827071` or `9909855395`

In 'WG: SCM1177278 9910808067RSV Meldung' I succeed in skipping SCM but i catch only the 1st number '1177278', i want to skip this one and catch the next sequence of 5 digits or more.

So i'm desesperately trying to find the good regexp to do this...

I tried
`(?!scm|SCM)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)`

Our basic regexp (not optimized at all lol) is: `([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)`

Comment: You just need a lookbehind, `(?<!scm|SCM)[0-9]{5,}`, or even `(?<!scm|SCM|\d)[0-9]{5,}` to also enforce a numeric boundary (that would need a different syntax if you use Python `re` though, since the length of alternative patterns is now not the same).

Comment: The trivial explanation why this would not work is that you are using a regex tool which doesn't support lookaheads. Please review the guidance in the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) and update your question with information about which tool or language you are using if indeed you have reason to believe that this should work.

Comment: My colleague finally found this one which is good :
(?<!SCM\d)\b([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)

I'm gonna test yours too !! Thx guys !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) powered regex like

```
(?<!scm|SCM|\d)[0-9]{5,}
(?<!scm|SCM)(?<!\d)[0-9]{5,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fy1WSA/1). Both patterns should work the same, the second one is for Boost/Python `re` that require fixed-width lookbehind patterns.

*Details*:

- `(?<!scm|SCM|\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `scm`, `SCM` or  digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `[0-9]{5,}` - five or more digits.

Comment: Ok so the winner is: 
(?<!scm|SCM|\d)([0-9]{5,}) 

Thx for the help, really loved it !!